# Linking a Button to a website and keeping the style

Tags: html

Hey Everyone:  I'm working on a simple login system and wanted to keep my styled buttons inline with each other in the form but assign different actions to them.  Is this possible?  Obviously the following code won't work as written.  I want the login button to link to my login.php script and my sign-up button to link to the signup.html page.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
            Username: 
        <input name="username" type="text" class="clear" size="20">
        <br><p></p>
            Password: 
            <input name="password" type="password" class="clear" size="20"><br><p></p>
            <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Log In">
             <input name="signup" type="button" id="signup" value="Sign Up">   
      </form>
```

As always thanks so much!

Comment: You have to either process both actions in the same php script (why not?) or use javascript on the client side which gives you much more flexibility for form submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use **javascript** for doing this
>
> **HTML**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
        Username: 
    <input name="username" type="text" class="clear" size="20">
    <br><p></p>
        Password: 
        <input name="password" type="password" class="clear" size="20"><br><p></p>
        <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Log In">

         <input name="signup" type="button" id="signup" onclick="loadsign();" value="Sign Up">   
  </form>
```

> you can use this **JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadsign(){
        window.location.assign( provide path of html file );
      }
</script>
```

> Hope this could help you !
> I have changed code a bit hope it could deliver.

Comment: Thank you for the help!.. obviously I'm missing something?

Comment: I went ahead and copied your code into the form and placed the script in the <head> of the page but is there a library to import that I'm missing? Also I added the $(document).ready(loadsign ..etc.)  to make sure the page loaded before the script ran

Comment: Hope you have put the code in javascript  inside <head></head> tag and provide path to your file between " " doublequotes .. Best of Luck .